# My regular expression isn't matching the correct group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
var str = ' not valid xml here <something unknown>123</something>\
<something hello>555</something>\
<something what>655</something>';
var matches = str.match(/something[^>]+>([^<]+)/g);
```

I want matches to equal `[123, 555, 655]` and I thought () around my regex indicated this, but for some reason matches equals `["something unknown>123", "something hello>555", "something what>655"]`. My solution was to do

```
matches.map(function(data){ return data.split('>').pop() })
```

but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this by directly editing the regex, and I was wondering why () did not work.

Comment: You should use an XML parser to parse your input, regex isn't the right tool for this.

Comment: First, as @Nit says, regex probably isn't the right tool here. But more importantly, your question was incomprehensible because it plainly wasn't the actual output. I've cleaned it up as best I can...

Comment: XML wont work for this as the output I'm parsing isn't valid XML, only parts of it are. The string I provided is an example.

Comment: @Macmee Are you just trying to match digits in your strings?

Comment: To answer the actual question, `match(/.../g)`  returns only topmost matches, all groups get lost. A workaround is to use `exec` in a loop, or `.replace` with a callback.

Comment: FYI, added demo of running javascript code to my answer outputting the data you want

Answer (score 0):

Macmee, with all the usual disclaimers about parsing xml in regex, here is a simple regex that captures what you want:

```
<[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/
```

See the [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/yI8dD5) (you are looking for the Group 1 captures in the bottom right pane).
Make sure you use `g` to get all the captures—but you already know that.

Here is also a full [code demo](http://js.do/code/38390) for the code below.

```
<script>
var subject = '<something unknown>123</something>\
<something hello>555</something>\
<something what>655</something>';
var regex = /<[^>]*>([^<]*)<\//g;
var group1Caps = [];
var match = regex.exec(subject);

// put Group 1 captures in an array
while (match != null) {
    if( match[1] != null ) group1Caps.push(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(subject);
}

document.write("<br>*** Matches ***<br>");
if (group1Caps.length > 0) {
   for (key in group1Caps) document.write(group1Caps[key],"<br>");
   }
</script>
```